# Excel Spreadsheet for tracking investments?

Tags: transaction-data

Does anyone have, or know of a crypto activity tracking spreadsheet? Nothing fancy, just a way to track when coins were acquired,for how much and when they were sold or traded. Ideally it would form the basis for generating a profit/loss statement for the IRS...

Answer (score 0):

If youve only bought from KYC-exchanges and arent concerned about privacy, cointracker.io seems to work well. Im only using the trial offered through coinbase, so i dont have all my accounts. But it just works, clean UI. Sign up in the 'tax center' in coinbase in order to easily set up.

But this is monero, so...